# VBA: access sheet from userForm

Tags: excel, vba, cell, selection

I am trying to access my workbook and sheets while I am in a subroutine of my UserForm.

My macro starts when the focus in the worksheet is changed:

```
Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    '...
End Sub
```

In my UserForm, I now wanted to define what happens when the red x on the top right is pressed. In that case I want to change the focus/selection in Sheet1 when that UserForm is closed. Though, I want to do this relative to the original position, so relative to **Target** or relative to the **ActiveCell**.

What works in the routine above is:

```
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
```

However, I would like to do this in the routine below:

```
Sub UserForm_Terminate()
    Me.Hide
    'change focus here
    End
End Sub
```

I was able to select a cell with

```
Sheet1.Cells(3, 3).Select
```

but that is obviously not relative to the original position. Neither **Target** nor **ActiveCell...** are available in UserForm_Terminate

I hope anyone can help

Vincenz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand what you're trying to achieve, but can't you simply use:

```
Application.ActiveCell
```

in `UserForm_Terminate`?

Comment: That was exactly what I wanted to to :)

  `Application.ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select`
Thank you so much!